# Keypad hide/show in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-keypad, android-input-method

I had tried this out. And it works fine with Samsung tablet.

> On Page 1_4.html i have to hide keypad and on 2.html I Have to show
> keypad.
>
> Both on textbox click inside webview
>
> NOTE: Android Activity is Same.
>
> I'm calling this code on `webView.setOnTouchListener`

```
        if (value.equals("1") || value.equals("4")) {
            
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
            
        } else if(value.equals("2")) {
            getWindow().clearFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
        }
```

But its not working in any mobile phones. It gives me **Warning**

> W/InputMethodManager(25060): startInputInner : InputBindResult == null

I have google it. But didn't find anything useful.

What should I do now? Any help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To open keypad try this

```
webview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
               MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
               keyboard.showSoftInput(webview, 0);
           }
},100);
```

To close keypad try this

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(MainActivity.this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code : This is working on all devices.

```
 try
 {
    if(isopen)
    {    
       // to hide keyboard
       InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }else{
       // to open keyboard
       InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(linearLayout.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    }
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) 
    {
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
    }
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47221/discussion-between-harsh-goswami-and-maulik-j)